# How to join a table that has a column level primary key to a table with a composite primary key in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgresql and trying to perform a join between a table that has a column level primary key (the key is only dependent on a single column) to a table with a composite primary key (the key is dependent on two columns). The table with the column level primary key shares only one column that is used in the other table's composite primary key. Is it possible to join these?

I have tried using this syntax:

```
SELECT
    t.passenger_name,
    SUM(tf.amount) AS total_amount
FROM
    tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket_flights AS tf ON t.ticket_no = tf.ticket_no
                         AND "____" = tf.flight_Id
GROUP BY 
    t.passenger_name
ORDER BY 
    total_amount DESC
```

The blank space ("___") represents the piece of information that I am missing. In the table `tickets`, the primary key is the `ticket_no` column. In the table `ticket_flights`, the primary key is a composite key of `ticket_no` and `flight_id` columns.

In simple terms, I am asking for the syntax used when joining a table with a column level primary key to a table with a composite primary key. The table with the column level primary key only has one of the columns used in the composite key of the other table.

When I join the tables using only the one column that they share (ticket_no; leaving out the AND clause) I get half of the sum I was expecting. Perhaps there are errors within the database, but I am curious about the proper syntax for performing such an operation.

Comment: could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), but - **no images**.

Comment: You can join tables on any combination of columns - whether they are designated as keys is irrelevant (though whether there are underlying indexes will affect performance). If you are joining on the only column you have and it doesn’t return the result you expect then you need to investigate your data and work out why

Comment: "When I join the tables using only the one column that they share (ticket_no; leaving out  the AND clause) I get half of the sum I was expecting" You should be able to provide data that shows the missing info (the research involved in doing so might actually answer the question along the way). Offhand, it seems like you might be asking to do something out of the realm of possibility (i.e., something along the lines of *I need to get a sum of particular flights on a ticket ... but I can't tell you which flights, just that I don't want all of them*).

Comment: When the table `tickets` also has a column `flight_id`, that's the one you need. But without the DDL for both tables, we can only guess. Some data would have been helpful as well. (all in plain text)

Comment: We ***really*** need to see the table definitions.